# Are Cmake/Autotools useful for non standard compilers?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I am working on a complex project written in C/Asm for an embedded target running on an Analog Devices DSP. The toolchain is close to gcc, but they are plenty of differences. Moreover, I am using a lot of autogeneration scripts using Jinja2 to generate header files from data extracted from a database. I also have plenty of compiler flags.

I currently wrote a Makefile from scratch. It is about 400 lines long and works pretty well. I automatically discover the sources across the directories and hold all the dependencies *i.e.*

```
a.tmpl --->jinja-->a.c--->a.o
             ^
a.yaml ------'
```

I would like to know if tools such as Cmake or Automake can be useful in my case. In other words, can I use these tools to simply the readability of Makefile?

Comment: The main point of the `autotools` package is to facilitate portability across compilers and build environments, something which I think I we may safely assume to be non-issue in your application. I would certainly look into more capable build tools however, such as `scons` or `cmake`. The ability to comfortably and reliably craft Rube Goldberg-esque build scripts should not be underestimated, just consider some of the insane C preprocessor or C++ template abuses being committed for the lack of flexible meta-programming facilities.

Comment: @doynax, I am not sure to understand the meaning of your last point.

Comment: Sorry but you've hit on something of a pet-peeve of mine, albeit tangentially. All I'm trying to say is that the meta-programming facilities available in C/C++ are rather limited and unfortunately many build systems make integrating external code generators and other meta-programming techniques sufficiently painful that it has become common to practice stretch macro and template hacks to ridiculous and unmaintainable lengths. Classic `make` mostly works yet it is surprisingly easy to miss dependencies and find yourself forcing a rebuild as an incantation at the first sign of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake works perfectly with generated sources. Just add appropriate custom command:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT a.c
    COMMAND jinja <args>
    DEPENDS a.yaml)

add_executable(a a.c)
```